# Cipher Alogrithm 'AES-256-GCM' Not Found (OpenVPN Error)

Tags: encryption, openssl, vpn, openvpn, aes-gcm

I was trying to connect to a .ovpn file using OpenVPN but when I try to connect it with this command:

```
sudo openvpn --config downloaded-client-config.ovpn
```

It failed with the following output:

```
Wed Jun 17 23:53:03 2020 OpenVPN 2.3.10 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jan  9 2019
Wed Jun 17 23:53:03 2020 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08
Wed Jun 17 23:53:03 2020 Cipher algorithm 'AES-256-GCM' not found (OpenSSL)
Wed Jun 17 23:53:03 2020 Exiting due to fatal error
```

My OpenSSL version: `OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018`

OpenVPN version: `OpenVPN 2.3.10`

Ubuntu Version: **16.04**

Also, I ran this command as well to see the list of ciphers I have:
`openvpn --show-ciphers`

and AES-256-GCM was not present in that in that list.
How can I add it manually if it's possible?

PS: I am kind of a layman with respect to OpenVPN

Comment: your ubuntu version is rather old. Condider upgrading to something more recent. It could be openvpn is still using openssl 0.9.8

Comment: Oh alright, will give this a try! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with the OpenVPN version. The `AES-256-GCM` cipher was added in version 2.4.

You can [follow these steps to install OpenVPN 2.4](https://gist.github.com/tienthanh2509/50094f55439e19af3a09911aa5c48852) on Ubuntu 16.04 at which point the cipher should properly work. The suggestion in the comments to upgrade your OS entirely would also work, but is certainly not necessary!

Comment: I'd like to point out that these suggestions can be deciphered in more detail by reading this document:
https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/OpenvpnSoftwareRepos and scrolling to "Debian / Ubuntu: Using OpenVPN apt repositories" - someone using a version other than 16.04 may miss the fact xenial should be replaced with the appropriate argument.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue trying to connect a 2.3.2 client to a 2.4.4 server. I referred to this [cipher negotiation reference](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/CipherNegotiation?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=pmd_3a0fd5515fdc75e6321fa769acbb40905f5330d7-1626941478-0-gqNtZGzNAfijcnBszQq6#Serverversion2.4Configuring:--cipher) and updated both server and client config to use cipher `AES-256-CBC`

When the 2.4 server is set to `AES-256-CBC`, the clients (also set to `AES-256-CBC`) negotiate the following ciphers:

```
2.5 - AES-256-GCM
2.4 - AES-256-GCM
2.3 - AES-256-CBC
2.2 - AES-256-CBC
```